# Include custom text within citation

Tags: latex, bibliography

I would like to add custom text right after citation year within a reference without a comma. For example, I need (UNISDR, 2016:18) to indicate the exact page number of the reference.

To add custom text of ":18" right after year, I add following into my latex citation:

\citep[:18]{UNISDR:2016aa}

Then the result becomes (UNISDR, 2016, :18). I need to get (UNISDR, 2016:18) without a comma and a space after year.